# How to eliminate Registry entries, long after the software was uninstalled

Tags: windows-registry

How to eliminate Registry entries, long after the software was
un-installed, and I have already (Using Full Permissions) manually deleted
them many times. They keep coming back.

Each night I run Macecraft's jv16PowerTools Registry Module, and there 
they are again.

These in particular are from a company called SpeedBit.
At one time I had both their "Video Accelerator" and 
"DAP-Download Accelerator Plus" programs installed.

Answer (score 7):

The best way I've seen is [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/). Amazing tool, can backup registry entries, and works wonders as a maintenance tool.

If they keep coming back, they're being recreated by something like a browser helper object, like a toolbar or something (which I believe DAP installs in IE). Check your IE installation and make sure that there aren't any crazy addons hiding there.

Comment: CCleaner could not clean DAP residues ...

Answer (score 1):

DAP is considered spyware/malware for some anti-spyware programs, maybe try scanning your Windows with "Spybot: Search & Destroy"

For future program deinstallations use Revo Uninstaller, it scans registry for uninstaller's leftovers :)

Comment: I love revo uninstaller

Answer (score 1):

If you want to figure out which program causes the Registry entries to re-appear, then [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) might help.

It includes a tool that lets you monitor every Registry change and which EXE made it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the Windows Installer Cleanup utility direct from Microsoft.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

Answer (score 0):

[CCleaner for removing old registry entries.](http://www.ccleaner.com/)

[Revo uninstaller for uninstalling software and deleting all traces leftover.](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Registry Easy](http://www.registryeasy.com) does a good job of cleaning the registry including uninstalls.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using Revo uninstaller. When uninstalling a program it gives you a list of associated files that you can check to delete. The problem is that sometimes these files can be used b other programs and you might get errors later on. If you're not sure what the file is then leave it just in case.